# Soft returns for math mode?

Tags: equations, formatting

I have long equations in math mode (single $) that are not breaking properly to start a new line. I am using \displaystyle but that doesn't seem to have any effect on the line break. I can force the equations to break using hard returns but I really need soft returns that only break the line if it runs overly long. Is this possible?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle y(t) = c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos(t)+c_{4}\sin(t)+e^{t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{5}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+c_{6}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+e^{-t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{7}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+c_{8}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

This equation runs past the margins and past the bounds of the page. I can force it to hard return manually by inserting \\, but I want soft returns that will only break the equation if and where it runs too long.

(Full explanation: I am creating equations using random numbers that are of variable size for a Diff. Eq. exam generator.)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Dave

Comment: math will only break after a relation or binary operator, as you have not provided a usable example it's hard to know where it would break in your case but it would break after + if not inside a `{}` group, if theer is enough flexibility in the white space to allow that

Comment: Please extend your code fragment to compilable small complete document ....

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have attempted to fix the example to make it compilable.

Comment: You can try adding `\allowbreak` in places where you would like a break to happen or if you want to give a bit more incentive try a slightly negative penalty, e.g. `\penalty-200`. This probably won't work inside a `sub_mlist`, e.g. a brace group or `\left...\right` pair.

Comment: Hi Henri, thanks for the comment. I have played around with \allowbreak and tried to make it work, but when it breaks, it stretches the equation inappropriately by adding space between the characters in what appears to be an attempt to justify it. Is there any way to allow the breaks without doing that?

Comment: @user3131222 -  Yes, it *is* justifying those lines.  Since you're apparently putting these expressions within an itemized list, setting that list ragged right would solve that problem, but may cause others.

Comment: The \raggedright in combination with \allowbreak (no penalty) worked best. Thanks again for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest that you employ `aligned` environments and provide either 1 or 2 explicit line break instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
y(t)&=c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos(t)+c_{4}\sin(t)\\
    &\quad+\exp(t\sqrt{2})\bigl[c_{5}\cos(t\sqrt{2})
     +c_{6}\sin(t\sqrt{2})\bigr]\\
    &\quad+\exp(-t\sqrt{2})\bigl[c_{7}\cos(t\sqrt{2})
     +c_{8}\sin(t\sqrt{2})\bigr]
\end{aligned}$

\item 
$\begin{aligned}[t]
y(t)&=c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos(t)+c_{4}\sin(t)
     +e^{\sqrt{2}t} \bigl[c_{5}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)
     +c_{6}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)\bigr]\\
    &\quad+e^{-\sqrt{2}t} \bigl[c_{7}\cos(\sqrt{2}t)
     +c_{8}\sin(\sqrt{2}t)\bigr]
\end{aligned}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Equations will break after relations or binary operators, but not within `\left..\right` or `{..}`  So you can simply use `\raggedright` or also get rid of the left right pairs which gives more possibilities and also produces better size paraentheses in these cases.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in} 
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X



\begin{enumerate}\raggedright
\item
  $\displaystyle y(t) =
  c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos(t)+c_{4}\sin(t)+e^{t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{5}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+
c_{6}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+
e^{-t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{7}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+
c_{8}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$

\item \let\left\relax\let\right\relax
  $\displaystyle y(t) =
  c_{1}e^{t}+c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{3}\cos(t)+c_{4}\sin(t)+e^{t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{5}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+
c_{6}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)+
e^{-t\sqrt{2}}\left(c_{7}\cos\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)+
c_{8}\sin\left(t\sqrt{2}\right)\right)$
\end{enumerate}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\end{document}
```